# Laravel file upload with dropzone.js

Tags: php, forms, laravel, dropzone

I have a strange issue when trying to upload files with `dropzone.js`. I wanted to upload all files in `public > file-archive` folder. If the folder doesn't exist, the request passes fine, though I don't see file uploaded.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->createArchiveFolder();
    Storage::disk('archive')->put($request->file->getClientOriginalName() . $request->file->getClientOriginalExtension(), $request->file);
}

protected function createArchiveFolder()
{
    if (!file_exists(public_path() . '/file-archive'))
        \File::makeDirectory(public_path() . '/file-archive', 777);
}
```

After this, the folder gets created (I tried creating it manually also and commenting out the create method). If I try to upload a file when folder exists, I get this:

[image]

My route:

```
Route::post('file-archive', 'FileArchiveController@store')->name('file-archive.store');
```

and my front end part:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'file-archive.store', 'class' => 'dropzone', 'files'=>true, 'id'=>'real-dropzone']) !!}

<div class="dz-message"></div>

<div class="fallback">
    <input name="file" type="file" multiple/>
</div>

<div class="dropzone-previews" id="dropzonePreview"></div>

<h4 style="text-align: center;color:#428bca;">Drop files in this area <span
            class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-down"></span></h4>

{!! Form::hidden('csrf-token', csrf_token(), ['id' => 'csrf-token']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to click in that error and then select the `response` tab to see what the error is.

Since you're getting an error `403`, I think the problem is with the token, you're creating a field called `csrf-token` but Laravel expects `_token`.

For future forms you can use the helper `{!! csrf_field() !}}` which will create the hidden input for you.